# Laravel + NextJs session value is null

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, next.js

Hello guys I'm using Laravel 9 with NextJs to build a ecommerce app with a shopping cart.
However when I list products I try to add them to session in Laravel, the value is always null.

Here is my NextJs code:

```
const addToCart = async (productId: number) => {
    console.log(productId)
    try {
      // add product to cart
      const rawResponse = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3001/product/add-to-cart/${productId}`);
      // get product data from session
      const cartData = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/products/cart`);

    } catch (e) {

    }
  }
```

I'm just passing `poductId`, and making sure Laravel saves that product in the session

Here is how my Laravel code looks like I have 2 routes in web.php : first for adding product to session, and second to list products

```
Route::post('product/add-to-cart/{id}', [ProductController::class, 'addProductToCart']);

Route::get('products/cart', [ProductController::class, 'getProductsInCart']);
```

**ProductController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller {
 
    public function addProductToCart(Request $request, $id) {
    
            $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

        $cart = session()->get('cart', []);

        if(isset($cart[$id])) {
            $cart[$id]['quantity']++;
        } else {
            $cart[$id] = [
                "productId"=> $product->id,
                "name" => $product->name,
                "quantity" => 1,
                "price" => $product->price,
            ];
        }

                  
        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return response()->json(['success' => 'success'], 200);
    }

    public function getProductsInCart(Request $request) {
        $cart =         session()->get('cart');
    
        var_dump($cart);


        return $cart;
    }
}
```

I have allowed CORS request

here is how my Kernel.php looks like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array<string, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,

        'isAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\isAdmin::class,
    ];
}
```

But for some reason in second route, when I log session it returns null

```
   $cart = session()->get('cart');
        
   var_dump($cart); // is null
```

Does anyone know what could be potential problem?